# Adding language or Contributing to ECMAScript Internationalization API localization

Tags: javascript, localization, ecmascript-intl

How do I contribute Internationalization API languages or add language ? In Mongolia we use different number formatting and date format, also when I need to format number in Mongolian I need to create custom function to do it. And I want to use `Intl API`, because

```js
const formattedNumber = Intl.NumberFormat('mn-MN', { notation: "compact" })
```

is better than writing function below

```js
function formatNumber (number) {
    if(number > 1000000000) return number / 1000000000 + " тэрбум"
    ///and so on
    return number;
}
```

I did little research and all the languages and variants are registered  [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) and subtags are listed in the [Unicode CLDR Project](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/bcp47). But when I use  `mn-Cyrl` or any other Mongolian locale it returns default `en-US` string. So I am wondering if I am able to contribute to Intl API localization.

Comment: what does `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('mn-MN', { notation: "compact" }).format(1000000000))` produce for you? for me, the output is `1 тэрбум` - which seems to be what you want

Comment: @JaromandaX yup. As I mentioned we can achieve it with custom function. But Intl object can be useful if it has Mongolian localization :).  Not only number format also date time, collator etc.

Comment: what custom function? I'm talking about the code `new Intl.NumberFormat('mn-MN', { notation: "compact" }).format(1000000000)` produces the exact result you want, without any custom function!

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now ... Chrome doesn't support `mn-MN` - I use Firefox, and that has supported `mn-MN` for a **long** time - sorry I misunderstood the source of the issue is chrome specific (even Edge, based on Chrome, supports `mn-MN` !!!)

Answer (score 2):

I see, you might need this. it's official

[proposal-intl-numberformat-v3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-numberformat-v3)